# retain data in text box while adding/deleting new row

Tags: jsf-2

I want to retain data in text box while adding/deleting other row.I am using nested datatable. If I click on delete button it refreshed entire datatable, so user lost the partially filled form data.

```
        <h:commandButton id="addBtn"  value="Add Value">
            <f:ajax listener="#{relationBean.addValue}" 
                render="datatableIterator" event="click" />
        </h:commandButton>
        <h:dataTable id="datatableIterator"
            value="#{relationBean.datatables}" var="datatable">
            <h:column>
                <h:dataTable id="relationIterator"  
                    value="#{datatable}" var="item">
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header"> Relation Type Name</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.relationType}" />
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">language</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.languageName}" />
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header"> Value</f:facet>
                <h:inputText value="#{item.relationForm}" />
            </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <p:commandLink action="#{relationBean.deleteDataTable}" 
            immediate="true" update="@form" process="@this" >
            <h:graphicImage value="../images/delete.png"  />
            <f:setPropertyActionListener 
                target="#{relationBean.deleteId}" value="#{datatable}" />
                 </p:commandLink>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Comment: This way you're processing only the `commandLink` component, but rerendering the whole form. No table data is sent to the managed bean and when you update it you've lost current inputs. What you want I think is to process the table (to keep its values) and also update the table itself. Don't know what your parent table id is, but `process="tableId" update="tableId"` should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

I got the resolution.
Its only one line change.what I was doing that I was adding the datata before populating the form, so whenever I click on delete button it clears the form. so I added the data after populating the form like this.

```
getDatatables().add(getRelationDTOList());
```

before it was

```
datatables.add(getRelationDTOList());
```

and included execute="@form" in xhtml add button.

Comment: The code change is irrelevant. `execute="@form"` did the trick ;-)